# Parse - Using User ACLs to share user information

Tags: parse-platform

I've got a question about the best way to allow user's information to be visible between users in certain situations.

For example, my app will have a "FriendRequest" class to model friend requests between users. The "FriendRequest" class has two User pointers, "toUser" and "fromUser".

I also set a default ACL for all user objects to restrict access to that user only for read/write.

My question is, when a user sends a friend request, I add the pointers for each user, and set the ACL of the "FriendRequest" object to allow both users to read and write to that object. However, when the user retrieves the friend request data, the "fromUser" data is not returned from the query because the ACL of the "fromUser" allows access to only that user - not to the other user who receives the friend request.

What is the best way to allow this data to be visible? Whenever a "FriendRequest" is created, should I add read permissions to the "fromUser" ACL for the "toUser" to be able to read it's information?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: I ended up just adding additional fields to the FriendRequest model, such as fromUserID, fromUserName, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok lets setup some sample data to make the example problem clearer.

In the `Users` table:

```
{objectId:"BBBB", name:"Bob", age:18, email:"bob@email.com", ACL: only Bob Read/Write} 
{objectId:"JJJJ", name:"Jane", age:27, email:"jane@email.com", ACL: only Jane Read/Write}
```

So Bob sends a friend request to Jane. You create a new object in the `FriendRequest` class.

```
{objectId:"XXXX", fromUser: <ptr to BBBB>, toUser: <ptr to JJJJ>, ACL: Bob and Jane Read/Write}
```

In your current setup, since you have setup the ACL so that noone else can read them.

**Option 1**

As you have suggested, when Bob makes the request to Jane, since it is initiated from a device where Bob is logged in, he can add Jane to the ACL. You will then need to remove Jane from the ACL either when she accepts or rejects the friend request, or perhaps after a certain amount of time.

This is simple when Jane needs to request data from Bob, as she can pull it from his user class, however it requires more management later on (ensuring the ACLs are reset properly later on, using a scheduled task to ensure that all friend requests not resolved after 2 weeks are "rest", finally, if there is some reason you are securing all user classes so that they are read only, temporarily making all of Bob's attributes readable to Jane might be a bad thing.

**Lazy Option**

You could just make all users read-to-all. More insecure obviously and something I imagine you want to avoid since you are using ACLs and posted this in the first place.

**Data Duplication Option** 
This requires temporarily data duplication, but then you are only the specific information you require, nothing more. Say you want `name` and `email` but not `age` from the user.

```
{objectId:"XXXX", 
fromUser: <ptr to BBBB>, 
fromUserName: 'Bob'
fromuserEmail: 'bob@email.com'
toUser: <ptr to JJJJ>, 
ACL: Bob and Jane Read/Write}
```

So when Bob creates the request, he puts his own info into the request object. Jane can read this info. Once the request is complete, you could make it so that Jane could read Bob's data, or you may have some other table `FriendRelations` which described these relationships (again, duplicating relevant data if this made things more secure for you).

Comment: at this step:retrieves the friend request data, the "fromUser" data is not returned from the query because the ACL of  ... you can use the parse 'master-key' on the read. see REST API Docs under section=updating roles where mentions"X-Parse-Master-Key". That will include the data you did not have authority to Get before including the new key in the headers.

Comment: @RobertRowntree I imagine if you deferred some of the functionality above to a Parse Cloud function, then you could use the master key. You wouldn't want to be using it on and end-user device though. (As it wouldn't be hard for a malicious user to obtain that key, then it would be game over for your data).

Comment: @ahar083 Thanks for your reply. I think either your Option 1 or the data duplication option is best here. This sort of raises another general question I had about how to make User information visible once a friend request is approved as well. For example, if they do approve a request, would I use the user's ACL to allow read access for all of their "friends"? I'd also considered creating a Role for each user, which would store a list of User relations that identifies their friends, and allow read access for that Role on the user's ACL. Thoughts?

Comment: @koriner Before going any deeper into the technicalities of how we might set things up, I should ask - is there any information within the "User" object, you would not want others to easily be able to access? For example if a User object contains a users First name, an Country, It would be fine (and simpler) to make it Readable to all users. If however it contained their DOB, home address, phone number, you probably don't want to make it sharable. Since in your initial problem, you said that you set user objects to non-readable by others, you must be storing some sensitive info right?

Comment: @ahar083 Yes - the User information will also contain email and phone number, data which we wouldn't want other users to be able to access, unless specifically granted access by the owner of the information. What would you suggest here, a solution involving Roles as I described above, or something else?

Comment: @ahar083 I've marked your answer as correct since you did help me clarify things. If you do have any more thoughts regarding my previous comment, it'd be helpful! Thanks.